# Boundaries in Double Integrals

Tags: integration

In regards to the following figurate of $f(x,y)=x$ in which $a=1$ and $b=10$, I was having some difficulty determining the boundaries of integration for the double integral. I assumed that $x=[1,10]$ and $y=[1,10]$. I also then tried $x=[1,10]$ and $y=[1,x]$ but the answer is coming up as incorrect when I compute the actual integral. I am also integrating with respect to $y$ first.

Am I making a mistake in the boundaries or computing the actual integral?[image]

Comment: What is the correct answer given to you?

Comment: I think your limits are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cylindrical coordinates such as below:

$f(x,y) = rcos\theta$

Thus $$I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{1}^{10} rcos\theta rdrd\theta$$

$$I = \frac{1998}{3}$$